# Xcode6 - Swift: How to detect which object is touched and move/drag/drop?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift

I'm trying to have more than one off these types:
@IBOutlet weak var objectToMove1: UIImageView

and want to be able to detect when one of them is touched... If held down on the object and moving finger, I want the object to follow.. when dropped, I want to see if it interfere with another object of the same type...

I found this example:

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    var touch : UITouch! = touches.anyObject() as UITouch
    location = touch.locationInView(self.view)     

    objectToMove1.center = location
}
```

This works, but only for the specific object (here: "objectToMove1")... And it moves to the position where I first put my finger (don't matter where I put my finger)...

So, how can I tweek this to be able to detect if I'm actually touching that object and only then follow my finger + detect if it interfere (collide) with another object when lifting my finger?

Thanx!
Kjetil

Answer (score 0):

Use a UITouchGestureRecognizer. You can create a general one which uses a delegate call to handle the touch. You can then add this to any views you create programatically or in a viewDidLoad type methop you can attach it there.

Comment: Hi and thanx... Unfortunally I'm realy new to swift, xcode and mac, so could you please give me a code example?

Comment: Maybe it's the PanGestureRecognizer I should use?

Answer (score 0):

FIXED!!!

Finally got pointed in the right direction and understood that we are dealing with "optional's", which I still don't fully understand (currently reading "The Swift Programming Language")...
Anyway, the solution was to put "!" after ".view"...

Credit to @DemetrakoPetros which helped me :-D

K.